# How do I convert a string to UTF-8 in Android?

Tags: java, android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am using a HTML parser called Jsoup, to load and parse HTML files. The problem is that the webpage I'm scraping is encoded in `ISO-8859-1` charset while Android is using `UTF-8` encoding(?). This is results in some characters showing up as question marks.

So now I guess I should convert the string to UTF-8 format.

Now I have found this Class called [CharsetEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) in the Android SDK, which I guess could help me. But I can't figure out how to implement it in practice, so I wonder if could get som help with by a practical example.

UPDATE: Code to read data ([Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url))

```
url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 4000);
```

Comment: Could you post the code used to read a html document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can let Android do the work for you by reading the page into a byte[] and then using the jSoup methods for parsing String objects.

Don't forget to specify the encoding when you create the string from the data read from the server using the correct String [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 4):

[Byte encodings and Strings](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
      String original = new String("A" + "\u00ea" + "\u00f1"
                                 + "\u00fc" + "C");

      System.out.println("original = " + original);
      System.out.println();

      try {
          byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");
          byte[] defaultBytes = original.getBytes();

          String roundTrip = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");
          System.out.println("roundTrip = " + roundTrip);

          System.out.println();
          printBytes(utf8Bytes, "utf8Bytes");
          System.out.println();
          printBytes(defaultBytes, "defaultBytes");
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

   } // main
```