# Android - concatenate two different languages strings

Tags: android, string, append, stringbuilder, multilingual

I can't find a solution to this "simple" action:

I'm trying to append 2 strings to get a full file path (folders and file name):

`String a = /storage/emulated/0/abc/לכ`/
 this has non-English letters and

```
String b = 20141231_042822.jpg

String c = a + b
```

the result:

```
/storage/emulated/0/abc/לכ/20141231_042822.jpg
```

(Tried with StringBuilder as well)

Comment: Convert that String to UTF-8 Format and then try to append it so it will work for u

Comment: I've tried the last example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161712/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-utf-8-in-android , still not working :/

Comment: Just to make it clear, the non-English language is written Right-to-Left, unlike English which is Left-to-Right

Comment: Use URLEncoder.encode("text","UTF-8"); Try this i guess it may works. for you :)

Comment: How should this be done with String a and String b ?

Comment: totally twisted results with URLEncoder

Comment: Does anyone have a different solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [BidiFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/text/BidiFormatter.html)

For [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/65e58fe/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/text/BidiFormatterSupport.java):

```
private static String text = "%s הוא עסוק";
private static String phone = "+1 650 253 0000";

String wrappedPhone = BidiFormatter.getInstance(true /* rtlContext */).unicodeWrap(phone);
String formattedText = String.format(text, wrappedPhone);
```

Comment: Still no luck with your proposal :\

Answer (score 0):

Use `char[]` instead and add them one by one using this method:

```
public char[] generatePath(String a, String b){
    if(a==null || b==null)
        return null;

    char[] result = new char[a.length() +b.length()];

    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
       result[i]=a.charAt(i);

    for(int i=a.length();i<a.length()+b.length();i++)
       result[i]=a.charAt(i);

    return result;
}
```

This would ensure that each character is in the right place.

> `String` objects in Java don't have an encoding (*).
>
> The only thing that has an encoding is a `byte[]`. So if you need
>   UTF-8 data, then you need a `byte[]`. If you have a `String` that
>   contains unexpected data, then the problem is at some earlier place
>   that incorrectly converted some binary data to a `String` (i.e. it was
>   using the wrong encoding).
>
> (*) that's not entirely accurate. Actually they have an encoding, but
>   that's UTF-16 and can't be modified.
>   source: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5729834/1364896)

What you have to do is to use `Byte[]` instead of String

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5729828/1364896)

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString);
```

or  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5729823/1364896)

```
byte[] ptext = String.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I've fixed your code to do what you meant it to do, the result char[] has the right sequence of chars, but when I new String(result) --> it twists the string once again.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, after calling generatePath() , how do I convert the char[] into a "good" String ?

Comment: use `new String(generatePath()a,b)` @MikoDiko

Comment: You have to be more specific @MikoDiko to allow us help you if you want. And also don;t forget if you find any or our answers somehow useful for you, vote it up as a appreciation for the time

Comment: added a small piece of info to the main post -- > Just to make it clear, the non-English language is written Right-to-Left, unlike English which is Left-to-Right